# Is it possible to detect if the hardware display has completed the process of switching between display modes?

Tags: operating-system, hardware, x86, low-level

The reason I ask is because I just bought a new LCD that takes approximately 5 seconds to change between display modes, such as from 1920x1080x32bpp to 1280x800x32bpp.  Does a programmatic solution exist to detect if the display is ready for video output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is 'no'. Once the display adapter starts transmitting a new signal in a new refresh rate, etc., it has absolutely no way of knowing how long it takes the display to internally process the change and start showing an image. This is a hardware limitation with both DVI and VGA signals, not a software one.